# too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Tags: python, logistic-regression

While splitting the data into training and testing using python, I am getting following error

```
" too many values to unpack (expected 3)"
```

Here's my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train = train_test_split(features,prices, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)
print("Training and testing split was succesful")
```

This is the expected output: `'Training and testing split was successful'`.

Comment: can you provide a more complete error log?

Comment: I got it resolved, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed y_test.

Try this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features,prices, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)
```

Comment: just realised.. thannks:)

Answer (score 0):

This is the document of train_test_split in sklearn: [sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

Here is the return:

> splitting : list, length=2 * len(arrays)
>
> List containing train-test split of inputs.

If you input features and prices, that means you put two inputs, each of which would be split into two parts, training and testing. So in order to obtain them, you should use `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test`, but you missed the last parameter.

Possibly you can correct your code like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features,prices, test_size=0.2, random_state=10) 
print("Training and testing split was successful")
```